# $\lim\limits_{R\to0^+}\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le R^2}e^{-x^2}\cos(y)dxdy=?$

Tags: integration, analysis

$$\lim\limits_{R\to0^+}\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le R^2}e^{-x^2}\cos(y)dxdy=?$$

First I want to show $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2}\cos(y)$ doesn't go crazy at $(0,0)$ otherwise it is already clearly continuous and bounded.

So $$|e^{-x^2}\cos(y)|\le e^{-x^2}\to 1$$ when $$x^2+y^2\to 0$$

So Now finite and bounded integrand's integral has to go 0 because region vanishes, but how to properly show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $|e^{-x^2}\cos(y)|$ is bounded by $1$ from above for any $x$ and $y$. So the absolute value of your integral is less than or equal to the area of the circle $x^2+y^2\leq R^2$ times $1$.